# JavaScript limiting my typed array length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a typed array from a SharedArrayBuffer.

```
let count = 4500;
let sab = new SharedArrayBuffer(count);
let arr = new Int16Array(sab);
```

now while running the code I noticed that all the components of the array were not getting processed.
when I console logging the lengths of the array I got the following output:

```
// when arr = new Int8Array(sab);
>> 4500
// when arr = new Int16Array(sab);
>> 2250
//when arr = new Int32Array(sab);
>> 1125
```

If its not a Int8Array its giving a wrong output. I also tried this with different values of count and found the wrong outputs on all of them. I am also not getting any errors in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly how the `Int8Array`, `Int16Array`, `Int32Array`, and `Float64Array` classes are built to function. You can see in the image on MDN's docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) on Typed Arrays that these arrays what is called an Array Buffer.

Each depth has items of twice the size, 16 bytes vs. 8 bytes and so on, and thereby half the length. The base number is 8. So when you set a count of `4500`, Int8Array will reflect that same number, but each depth past that (`Int16Array`, `Int32Array`, and `Float64Array`) will reduce that count by half with each step.

[image: Typed arrays in an ArrayBuffer]

You can see this in action, and the `Float64Array` function here:

```js
let count = 9000;
let sab = new SharedArrayBuffer(count);
let sab_depths = [
  ['Int8Array', new Int8Array(sab)],
  ['Int16Array', new Int16Array(sab)],
  ['Int32Array', new Int32Array(sab)],
  ['Float64Array', new Float64Array(sab)]
];
console.log(`Count: ${count}`)
sab_depths.forEach(([depth, array]) => console.log(`${depth}: ${array.length}`));
```